# How to wire my ultrasonic power driver board

Tags: power-supply, transformer, ultrasound

I recently bought the following product off amazon:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XGF5QZ8/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XGF5QZ8)

It didn't come with any instructions on how to wire, but based on the wire gauge for the input and the notice "Cannot load electricity" I imagine I need a power supply for it.

I saw that some people were using computer power supplies to power similar boards, however computer PSU's convert AC -> DC which in theory wouldn't work on the input transformer which draws it.

Could I in theory just put rate limiting resistors in series with the transform inputs and then hook it up directly to the wall?

Comment: seriously, don't buy devices without datasheets and instructions and then ask "the internet". It's a supplier's job to offer these, and if they don't, they are, imho, not worthy of your business – and even more so, I cannot support the business model of leaving customers in the rain, letting them ask someone else. Those are R&D, production and test costs that these manufacturers save themselves and burden the general public with.

Comment: There's no documentation anywhere, even with different driver boards. I would have thought that there might have been some unspoken industry standard on how to wire these up.

Comment: Never assume any sort of standardisation when it comes to dev kits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Amazon page:

> AC110V (-15 ~ + 10%), 50Hz,100w

It would appear that you can connect it directly to line voltage. The presence of a fuse and a "110V" checkbox on the PCB seem to confirm this.

However, you have bought a product without a datasheet and there will always be risk involved as a result.

Comment: Yep it worked. I was too scared to try it at first, thanks for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 0):

Not only is power essential but a transducer wall to act as stiff diaphragm to SS tank wall to radiate waves for fluid cleaning of PCB.

Examine how cleaning tanks are designed for consideration and possibly epoxy mounting of surface to wall. Think of it like a planar 40kHz tweeter, like some electrostatic speakers or more like sonar thru an aluminium stiff boat (hull). Research it and beware , anything resonates including stiff walls which can amplify or absorb vibration or simply pass thru depending on resonant frequency.